# adding click on page load in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two tabs. there is HTML assigned to both the tabs.when i open the page i want one of the tab to be clicked automatically.

My front page is coming empty.when I click on one of the tab then only it is showing the data. i want one of the tab to be shown on page opening. 
My Code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
        <ul>
            <li h><a  id="devices">devices</a></li>
            <li><a id= "tags">tags</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$#devices).trigger('click');
$("#devices").click(function(){
    //some code
});
$("#tags").click(function(){
    //some code
});
```

Comment: `$('#devices').trigger('click');` Typo?

Comment: `$('#devices').trigger('click');` put this after definition of click events

Answer (score 0):

You can use `click` trigger, but you must use it after .click event is declared:

```
// your click event declaration
$("#devices").click(function(){
    //some code
});

// trigger    
$("#devices").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#devices").click(function () {
    //some code
});
$("#tags").click(function () {
    //some code
});
$(function () {
    $("#devices").click();
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raskalbass/yU599/)

Comment: please include some explanation along with the code. These questions remain for years so future readers would know what they are into.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
$(function(){

        $("#devices").click(function(){
              //some code
        });

        $("#tags").click(function(){
              //some code
        });

        $("#devices").trigger('click');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       <div class="main">
            <ul>
                <li><a id="devices">devices</a></li>
                <li><a id= "tags">tags</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <script>
    $("document").ready(function()
    {
        $("#devices").click(function(){alert("A")})

        $("#tags").click(function(){alert("A1")})

        $("#devices").trigger('click');
    }); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='#tab1'>Link1</a></li>
  <li><a href='#tab2'>Link2</a></li>
<ul>

<script>
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#tab1').click();
        });
</script>

or more generic,using hash tags,In below code if url has #code then it will automatically click 2nd tab eg: www.text.com/index.html#tab2

$(window).load(function () {
if(window.location.hash!="" && window.location.hash=='#tab2'){
   $('#tab1').click();
}else {
   $('#tab2').click();
}
});
```